# registering achievements for facebook game

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, achievements

I have registered one achievement for my app. Everything is fine, but the problem is that, when user clicks on the achievement on the ticker, he gets redirected to a not existing page in my app. This is really strange. I made many tests and read several QA here in SO, but none of them helped me.
Let me explain better.
I put the following file on my server:
//achievements/achl1.php
the og:url meta tag is:
//achievements/achl1.php

When user cliks on the ticker, he gets redirected to:
http://apps.facebook.com///achievements/achl1.php

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer,  the prolem was that you must use https in order to have the redirect working as expected

Answer (score 0):

First of all og: url is required and you must supply a valid url. You can make a valid html page as achl1.php ( and provide additional info for the achievement or redirect to different location )

Comment: Hi there, the prolem was that you must use https in order to have the redirect working as expected